# Removing footer from SSIS Flat File

Tags: ssis

How do you deal with a flat file footer in SSIS? There is an option to get rid of header row(s) but there does not seem to be an (obvious) way to go about removing the footer. In my situation I actually have to remove 19 lines of footer rows from my flat file.

I have thought about using a script task to achieve this, but it seems like overkill.

What is the best way to remove multiple lines of footer info from the end of a file file in SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good way to remove the footer rows besides the script task. I have used the script task to add/remove headers and/or footers before a couple times in some of my packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional split tool to remove the header data. As long as the footer has something (record identifier)you can use to identify footer records.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a script task.  Find the footer, the remake the file without it.